# Looping into bullet points w/ google script and html template

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-email

Issue I am facing:

I have a spreadsheet with cells that will populate an HTML template for emails through Google Apps Script. These cells are linked to a list of bullet points in the HTML template that I would like to vary from 1 - 6 bullets in length, based on whether or not the cells have information in them or not. I am currently struggling to find a way to loop the cells without including blank bullet points in the final email.

I have researched various similar methods but nothing has quite been able to fit with the amount of looping and bulleting necessary in my script.

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
 template.tweb = web.getRange(1,1).getValue();
 template.tweb1 = web.getRange(2,1).getValue();
 template.tweb2 = web.getRange(3,1).getValue();    
 template.tweb3 = web.getRange(4,1).getValue();
 template.tweb4 = web.getRange(5,1).getValue();
 template.tweb5 = web.getRange(6,1).getValue();
```

I currently have it set up without a loop because I was unable to get more than the last row to populate the HTML template.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<p><strong>Website Development</strong></p>
<em>Weekly Highlights</em>
<br>
<ul>
 <li>The Website Development team completed the following:</li>
  <ul><li> <?= tweb ?></li></ul>
  <ul><li> <?= tweb1 ?></li></ul>
  <ul><li> <?= tweb2 ?></li></ul>
  <ul><li> <?= tweb3 ?></li></ul>
  <ul><li> <?= tweb4 ?></li></ul>
  <ul><li> <?= tweb5 ?></li></ul>
```

Additionally, here is an example of my failed looping code:

```
var e = pr.getLastRow();
 for (var i = 1; i < e+1 ; i++ ) {
 var tpr = pr.getRange(i,1).getValue();
 }
   template.tpr = tpr;
```

```
<p><strong>Public Relations</strong></p>
<em>Weekly Highlights</em>
<ul>
 <li><?= tpr ?></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Your loop reassigns `var tpr` over and over again. Is this something that you do on purpose ? Then it just adds the final reassigned value to template.tpr

Comment: @MariosKaramanis no, the intention was to assign a variable I can include with the HTML template that will have multiple rows of data. Do you have a recommendation on how to do this differently?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. It's worthy to note that the official docs about the use of scriptlets has an example of using loops in a HTML template.

Comment: So is your intention to add an ```li``` element for each of the ```tweb``` rows and if the row is blank to not add that ```li``` element?

Answer (score 2):

### In your case the best is to use [Apps Script scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#apps_script_code_in_scriptlets)

They allow you to create your html dynamically, integrating loops and statements with your html code.

**Sample:**

*Code.gs*

```js
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  return template.evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  var web = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  return web.getRange(1,1,6,1).getValues();
}
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><strong>Website Development</strong></p>
<em>Weekly Highlights</em>
<br>
<ul>
 <li>The Website Development team completed the following:</li>
  <? var data = getData(); ?>
   <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
     <? if (data[i][0]!="" && data[i][0]!=" ") { ?>
       <ul><li> <?= data[i][0] ?></li></ul>
     <? } ?>
   <? } ?>
  </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```